# Calling a GWT service in a different context than the GWT Module Base?

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, gwt-rpc

I have a GWT module with the X-GWT-Module-Base `http://host:8080/foo/` and would like to call a (GWT) service which is located at `http://host:8080/bar/`. The reason is for example that I want to be able to share a GWT service between two different GWT client projects.

All I've gotten to work so far is if the service is located within the module context, i.e. `http://host:8080/foo/bar` works fine, using `@RemoteServiceRelativePath("bar")` in my service interface.

It seems that the `@RemoteServiceRelativePath` only allows a value relative to the module base URL...so is there some other way to accomplish what I'm trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ended up finding the answer myself [right here](http://osdir.com/ml/Google-Web-Toolkit/2010-02/msg01666.html):

> the problem appears because of the RemoteServiceRelativePath as you
>   noticed it says relativepath,
>   one way to fix that is to use
>
> ```
>   ((ServiceDefTarget)gwtService).setServiceEntryPoint("/some/absolute/path");
> ```
>
> or use the power of the relative path (that's how i do it, because I'm
>   lazy)
>
> ```
>   @RemoteServiceRelativePath("../servX")
> ```
>
> which instead of /modB/servX or /modA/servX will become /servX no
>   matter what module calls it
>   also you'll need to make the proper changes in web.xml so that the

Comment: You can tick yourself off as the answer. +1 from me.

Comment: I'll just add that `gwtService` here is the name of the async service object you got back from GWT.create, and you should call setServiceEntryPoint just after you call GWT.create. This is such a frustrating solution... it makes life quite difficult for the client projects (I'd rather wrap up the URL details in the library). Oh well.